# How to hide EditText cursor when activity starts

Tags: android

When activity starts the EditText put cursor automatically without shows keyboard.

And when I finish use EditText and hide keyboard the cursor still shows.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/m_a_0_search_shape"
        android:hint="@string/m_a_0_search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/m_a_0_search"
        android:textColorHint="@color/m_a_0_search"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Coped

Solution

1) Set in your xml under your EditText:

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

2) Set onClickListener:

```
iEditText.setOnClickListener(editTextClickListener);

OnClickListener editTextClickListener = new OnClickListener() 
{ public void onClick(View v) 
{  if (v.getId() == iEditText.getId()) 
    {
        iEditText.setCursorVisible(true);
    }

}
};
```

3) then onCreate, capture the event when done is pressed using OnEditorActionListener to your EditText, and then setCursorVisible(false).

```
iEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
                iEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
            if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == 
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) 
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(iEditText.getApplicationWindowToken()
,InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will hide cursor forever

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the cursor from edittext programmatically you can use

```
edit_search.clearFocus();
```

This will shift the cursor to next focusable item in your layout if any.